# cannot read the next data row for dataset

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I get a error message I preview my report. I had to change my credentials for data server and changes the column names, but I didn't make any changes to the query. I get this error messages when I preview my report

> An error occurred during local report processing. An error has
>   occurred  during report processing. Cannot read the next data row for
>   the data set.  conversion failed when converting from a character
>   string to  uniqueidentifier.

I have two parameters both take number values so, I have them setup as text values. I have one more filter converting it to int. I changed my parameters to int and removed to filter to see if it worked, but I still get the same error message. The report worked when I ran it through my other credentials, I don't know why it giving me an error message now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As The error already pointing out, you have *character data type* which cannot be converted to *unique identifier type*.

you have data type mismatch

Comment: one of my column is originally varchar in the table so converting to int. if even i take out the conversion i still get the error message

Comment: the problem is one of your column has char type but you are trying to map it with uniqueidentifier.  Int is irrelevant here